# R rstats How to replace a single character in one place in a string

Tags: r, string, substring

I'm trying to write a function that will take a string and replace one character with another, but I want it to return every permutation of replacing that character. I'd like to replace every i with an l but I don't want to do it globally like in gsub and I don't want to do just the first one like in sub. I think an example illustrates it best. If I pass in the name keviin (with two i's):

```
thisFunction("keviin")
[1] kevlin keviln kevlln
```

So I get back replacing the first i, the second i and then both i's. This sounds like a job for recursion, but first I need to figure out how to replace just the first i. Then I could pass the resulting string to the function to get the next permutation.

Anybody got an idea to give me a push? I've tried doing this but it didn't work for me:

```
> substr("keviin",4,4) <- "l"
Error in substr("keviin", 4, 4) <- "l" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @CarlWitthoft idea, how about this:

```
thisFunction<-function(x) {
  xsplit<-strsplit(x,"")[[1]]
  ipos<-as.vector(gregexpr("i",x)[[1]])
  if (length(ipos)==1) {
    if (ipos<0) return(x) else {
      substring(x,ipos,ipos)<-"l"
      return(x)
    }
  }
  combos<-unlist(lapply(seq_along(ipos),combn,x=ipos,simplify=FALSE),recursive=FALSE)
  ret<-t(vapply(combos,function(x) {xsplit[x]<-"l";xsplit},character(length(xsplit))))
  do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep=""),as.data.frame(ret))
}

    thisFunction("keviin")
    #[1] "kevlin" "keviln" "kevlln"
```

Comment: This seems to work for my torture test  "keviinandinandfoiiiiquerbar" . Per my notes in my answer, I expected `2^7 - 1` results and in fact got 127 .

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of regex and sampling from a vector?

```
kevsplit<-unlist(strsplit('keviin',''))
the_eyes <-which( grepl('i',kevsplit))
kevsplit[sample(the_eyes,1)] <-"L"
newkev<-paste(kevsplit,collapse='')
```

That will randomly swap out one of the "i"s.  To swap out all possible permutations, 
do something like

```
for(j in 1:length(the_eyes) ) {
       calculate all permutations of the_eyes taken j at a time
       swap those selected values to kevsplit and save in some list
       }
```

I'm too lazy to write out that last bit :-)

EDIT: to clarify,  aside from pasting things back together again, your problem is basically:

For a vector of type c(0,0,0,0,0,....)  (replacing your "i" with 0 or logical FALSE), how many ways can you replace 1 or more values with a "TRUE" (or 1) ?  That's a standard problem in introductory combinatorics -- and happily enough for us computer weenies, turns out to be counting in binary!

Answer (score -1):

This works with objects but not pure strings in quotes for some reason

```
thisFunction <- function(x){
+     
+     substr(x,4,4) <- 'l'
+     return(x)
+     
+ }
> thisFunction('keviin')
[1] "kevlin"
```

works.

Comment: he wants the function to return 3 strings for the one input "keviin"

Comment: no he wanted the function to replace one character... he literally said "but first I need to figure out how to replace just the first i". He didn't ask for the whole solution, he just wanted to be able to replace one character first and then do the rest on his own.

Comment: if he wanted the whole function, he would've said how do I write a function to return every permutation of replacing one character, not "How to replace a single character in one place in a string"

Comment: he said thisFunction("keviin") should return
[1] kevlin keviln kevlln. You're right that he wasn't explicit.